# ¿Como hacer un incremento de un valor cada 3 registros insertados?

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos, mi problema es que cada 3 registros insertados debo hacer un aumento del valor, ejemplo: tengo mi tabla detalles_cuotas en la que guardo los montos de cada cuota segun una cantidad establecida, pero cada vez que inserte 3 registros debe aumentarse el monto un 20%. Esta es la funcion en la que hago la insercion:

```
function cuotas($cantidad,$monto){

$query = "INSERT INTO cuotas (cantidad,monto)VALUES('$cantidad','$monto')";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);

$val = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

for($i=1; $i <= $cantidad; $i++){
  $query2 = "INSERT INTO 
detalle_cuotas(id_cuota,monto)VALUES('$val','$monto')";
  $sql2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
}

if($sql>0 && $sql2>0):
  header('Location:admin.php');
else:
  echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
endif;
}
```

[[image: Tabla detalle_cuota] Asi deberian quedar los datos en mi tabla, cada 3 que inserte aumente el 20%, pero de verdad no consigo la forma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omQmy.png)

Comment: ¿PHP posee un *endif*? te comento para que no des tantas vueltas, antes de colocar código con petición pruebalo funcione; en un planteamiento que colocaste pusiste al parecer una parte de la solución que te indique pero en el *for* en vez de poner **$i=0** pusiste **$i=1** por eso incrementaba el tercer elemento y no el cuarto (como mencionaste); analiza el código no es solo copiar y pegar las sugerencias. Suerte.

Comment: Ya solucionado, efectivamente probe algo de lo que me habias dicho hace rato, con el if despues del for. y ya me incremeta cada 3 registros. Gracias Roberto.

Comment: Y claro que analizo el codigo Roberto, lo que paso fue que cambie la forma de mi tabla, anteriormente tenia varios campos, ahora es diferente. Pero ya esta, gracias por de nuevo por tu ayuda de hace rato